# How to make a post request to a rails app using android and retrofit

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, api, retrofit

I have setup rails api using the scaffold generator. so my controller looks like this

**Rails PostsController**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    render json: @posts
  end

  def show
    render json: @post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :userId)
    end
end
```

running this curl command

curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" www.example.com/posts/ -d '{"title":"foo", "body":"bar"}'

```
{"id":4,"title":"foo","body":"bar","created_at":"2017-06-12T19:11:26.752Z","updated_at":"2017-06-12T19:11:26.752Z"}
```

I then setup the android app following this tutorial [Sending Data With Retrofit 2 HTTP Client for Android](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845)

running the app using the [link](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) on the tutorial works.when I replace it with my rails app url I get the following

```
06-12 21:44:01.352 31991-31991/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-12 21:44:01.365 31991-31991/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-12 21:44:01.403 31991-31999/? E/zygote: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
06-12 21:44:01.403 31991-31999/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
06-12 21:44:01.494 31991-31991/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-12 21:44:01.600 31991-31991/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-12 21:44:01.614 31991-32018/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline

                                                   [ 06-12 21:44:01.635 31991:32018 D/         ]
                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa95e4f00, tid 32018
06-12 21:44:01.637 31991-32018/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-12 21:44:01.637 31991-32018/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-12 21:44:01.637 31991-32018/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
06-12 21:44:01.637 31991-32018/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
06-12 21:44:01.640 31991-32018/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa718b220: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
06-12 21:44:01.655 31991-32018/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa718b220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa95ccb10)
06-12 21:44:01.668 31991-32018/? W/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::Mapper: getService: found null hwbinder interface
06-12 21:44:01.672 31991-32018/? I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so from the current namespace instead.
06-12 21:44:01.707 31991-32018/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa718b220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa95ccb10)
```

and submitting the form give me

```
06-12 21:46:52.742 31991-31997/com.kainet.retropost I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=90KB
06-12 21:46:52.743 31991-31997/com.kainet.retropost I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=90KB
06-12 21:46:52.743 31991-31997/com.kainet.retropost I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the base_url from

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/api/v1";
```

to

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/";
```

and the interface from

public interface APIService {

```
@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Imei> sendPost(@Field("title") String title);
```

}

to

public interface APIService {

```
@POST("/api/v1/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Imei> sendPost(@Field("title") String title);
```

}